# assigning a CSS fontFamily ending with a number

Tags: javascript, html, css

so it seems that if I assign a font family ending with a number it doesn't stick

```
a = document.createElement("div")
a.style.fontFamily = "Arial"
```

and a is then

```
<div style="font-family: Arial; "></div>
```

BUT

```
a = document.createElement("div")
a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy Bookletter 1911"
```

and a is then

```
<div></div>
```

I'm pretty sure its the ending number that is the problem. Since

```
a = document.createElement("div")
a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy Bookletter blablabla"
```

and a is then

```
<div style="font-family: 'Goudy Bookletter blablabla'; "></div>
```

Is this a bug? I'm doing this in chrome 16

Comment: You should set up a http://jsfiddle.net so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something about the spaces and numbers causes a problem when setting font-family. Enclosing the font-family name in single quotes allowed it to work in Chrome 16 for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMxS4/1/

```
a.style.fontFamily = "'Goudy Bookletter 12'";
```

Without the quotes I saw the following odd behavior

```
a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy Bookletter12"; //works
a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy 12Bookletter"; //works
a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy 12 Bookletter"; //does not work
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html):

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted
>   as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation
>   characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in
>   unquoted font family names.

Regarding identifiers:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

This means that unquoted `Goudy Bookletter 1911` is an invalid font family, because 1911 is not a valid CSS identifier. `"Goudy Bookletter 1911"` is valid, though, as is unquoted `Goudy Bookletter blablabla`.

Therefore, you should use

```
a = document.createElement("div")
a.style.fontFamily = '"Goudy Bookletter 1911"'
```

By the way, `a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy\\20 Bookletter\\20 1911"` is also valid, and so is `a.style.fontFamily = "Goudy Bookletter \\31\\39\\31\\31"`. Both work in Chrome 16, but this kind of trickery is of course not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary checks show that browsers don't parse `fontFamily` property, when a numeric value is inside it. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/5qvZd/1/). I'm gonna write more about this.

It seems that if you remove the space in the font name, which contains numeric value, it won't encounter a problem. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/5qvZd/2/) now.

[If a font-family name contains whitespace, it must be quoted](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontfamily.asp). This means that you should wrap your font name, inside quotes (single or double). Check this last [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/5qvZd/3/).

Comment: w3schools is technically wrong here, font-family: Helvetica Neue is correct (although always quoting multi-word font-families is safer). An unquoted sequence of one or more identifiers is a correct font-family, but an identifier cannot start with a digit, which is why Goudy Bookletter 1911 does not work.