# Numbers in font family name in jQuery css() don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this line of code:

```
jQuery('body').css({'font-family': 'Exo 2', 'font-weight': 400});
```

and the resulting HTML is:

```
<body style="font-weight: 400;">
```

When I run

```
jQuery('body').css({'font-family': 'Exo', 'font-weight': 400});
```

the resulting HTML is:

```
<body style="font-family: Exo; font-weight: 400;">
```

Does anyone have any idea why would "Exo 2" not work in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font names with spaces need quotes around them.

You need to use:

```
jQuery('body').css({'font-family': '"Exo 2"', 'font-weight': 400});
```

Comment: Yes, it works with additional quotes. Thanks! Why does `jQuery('body').css({'font-family': 'Exo Two', 'font-weight': 400});` work without quotes?

Comment: @Jimsea hmm...I don't know. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Not a jQuery bug though, if using `Exo 2` straight in JS it fails. http://jsfiddle.net/bwcdsgqt/ If you inspect foo it has no `style` set, change the JS so the font family is `Exo` and when run the element will have the `style` attribute as expected.

Comment: It's in the specification actually, second answer here explains it well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951584/assigning-a-css-fontfamily-ending-with-a-number

Comment: @gillesc yes, it seems that it's legitimate to *not* have to quote font family names with spaces. But when left unquoted, none of the font name parts can begin with a digit. Seems to be a very odd rule but it was it is. Best to always quote to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you code results in CSS like:

```
font-family: Exo 2;
```

The correct notation would be:

```
font-family: "Exo 2";
```

In other words, try:

```
jQuery('body').css({'font-family': '"Exo 2"'});
```